# Safari wrong margins - working fine in Chrome & FF

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, safari, margin

I have a problem with some divs on Safari, the margins are completely messed up.

The weird part is that it works perfectly fine on Chrome & Firefox. If I implement a fix made especially for Safari, it gets messed up on the others.

Help ?

Thanks !

Comment: Do you have a link to the site?

Comment: Are you using a CSS reset?

Comment: @Steve Yes I am, but doesn't help.

Comment: Then, show some code, including the CSS reset.

Comment: @MitchellLayzell yes, it's rhinno.partners.org, the website isn't completely done, but the main problem with safari is the "drawer" that comes down in the middle when hovering. It should be centered, like it is on chrome & FF. Thanks!

Comment: Also, do the cases where the margins are off involve margins AND widths on the same element?  I.e. is it an issue with the box model?

Comment: Also, @Steve this isn't the final version (the css reset isn't online now, but i'm testing locally and it doesn't make a difference)

Comment: I don't see a problem in your example.  Both tabs look exactly the same to me in Safari and Chrome.  The only difference is the position of the half-round "tab".  In Safari, it is positioned all the way on the left, because you are positioning it `absolute`ly and don't provide a `left` property.  If you add `left: 50%` to `#pull_link`, everything looks the same.

Comment: @anas It's your drop down menu that's messing up on safari right?

Comment: @Steve thank you Steve, that fixed my problem ! Weird that this problem only showed up in Safari though.

Comment: Glad that that fixed it.   I will add it as an answer, so you can mark it as helpful. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is caused by a missing `left` declaration.  Add this to your CSS:

```
#pull_link {
    left: 50%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may have a small error/errors in your code that is tripping you up (e.g. perhaps you are missing a closing tag that would cause container collapse and then your clear fix is not working). Check safari developer tools against chrome developer. You should be able to locate the problem that way. Sometimes one browser will function with an error another will not. Without more information it is hard to be conclusive here. Have you tried w3c validating the html http://validator.w3.org/ ? You can catch missing syntax that way also.

Comment: Your design breaks in chrome as well when the browser window is  resized to be smaller. Your image `<img src="images/pull.png">` is currently being aligned using `#nav_div {text-align: center;}` drawer.css line 30. This is what is breaking in safari. Not a solution but hopefully a start.